# How make react countdown timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, countdown

i'm trying to do countdown timer with react. It will be basically countdown from 10 to 0 and when 0 i will call some function.

i found ideally for me some example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0q453m77nw?from-embed 
but it's a class component i wan't to do that with functional component and hooks but i can't.

i tried:

```
function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(10);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSeconds(setInterval(seconds, 1000));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    tick();
  });

  function tick() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      setSeconds(seconds - 1)
    } else {
      clearInterval(seconds);
    }
  }

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <div
        {seconds}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it's count down from 10 to 0 very quickly not in 10 seconds. 
where i mistake ?

Comment: Why use a hook? This is basically just as much code as a regular component.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans While it's about the same amount of code (at least in the current setup), there are other reasons to prefer a functional component over a class component. Functional components are often easier to read, easier to test, and the React team claims there might be performance incentives in future versions of React.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears the multiple `useEffect` hooks are causing the countdown to run more than once per second.

Here's a simplified solution, where we check the `seconds` in the `useEffect` hook and either:

- Use `setTimeout` to update `seconds` after 1 second, or
- Do something else (the function you want to call at the end of the countdown)

There are some downsides to this method, see below.

```js
function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(10);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
    } else {
      setSeconds('BOOOOM!');
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {seconds}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Downsides**

Using `setInterval` has the downside that it could be stopped - for example, the component is unmounted, you navigate to a different tab, or close your computer. If the timer requires more robustness, the better alternative would be to store an `endTime` in the state (like a global store or context) and have your component check the current time against the `endTime` to calculate the countdown.

Answer (score 3):

Do you care about precision? If so, you don't want setInterval. If you don't care about precision (and you probably don't) then you can schedule a call to `tick()` on an interval, not the other way around.

```
const TimeoutComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { countdown: 10 };
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.tick(), props.timeout || 10000);
  }

  tick() {
    const current = this.state.countdown;
    if (current === 0) {
      this.transition();
    } else {
      this.setState({ countdown: current - 1 }); 
    } 
  }

  transition() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    // do something else here, presumably.
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="timer">{this.state.countDown}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your logic a little bit. In the current situation your `useEffect` where you run your `tick` method is running on every render. You can find a naive example below.

```
function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(10);
  const [done, setDone] = useState(false);
  const foo = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
        setSeconds(prevSeconds => prevSeconds - 1)
    }
    foo.current = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000)
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds  === 0) {
      clearInterval(foo.current);
      setDone(true);
    }
  }, [seconds])

  return (

    <div className="App">
    {seconds}
    {done && <p>Count down is done.</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the first effect we are doing the countdown. Using callback one for setting state since interval creates a closure. In the second effect we are checking our condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use this snippet, As it will also help to memoize the timeout callback.**

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(60);    
const timeOutCallback = useCallback(() => setTimer(currTimer => currTimer - 1), []);

useEffect(() => {
  timer > 0 && setTimeout(timeOutCallback, 1000);
}, [timer, timeOutCallback]);

console.log(timer);
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else.

Happy Coding!